# How to have Concurrency Token RowVersion in Model but not mapped in database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, concurrency, entity-framework-core

I want to have a concurrency token field called `RowVersion` in my model, **and** use it to avoid concurrency conflicts in update, but I do not want it to be mapped to database when migrating my models into database. How can this be achieved?

This is my example entity model:

```
public class EntityModelBase : IEntityModel
{
    public EntityModelBase()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "شناسه سیستمی"), Column("Id", Order = -1)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Timestamp]
    [Column("RV", TypeName = "rowversion", Order = byte.MaxValue)]
    public virtual byte[]? RowVersion { get; } = new Guid().ToByteArray();
}
```

I tried to add `NotMapped` attribute on the `RowVersion` property of my entity model. This will avoid creating the column in database but Entity Framework returned it as NULL every time. What is correct usage to have support for concurrency token from Entity Framework, but never create column in the database for it?

Comment: When loading an existing entity - where do you get the concurrency token from, when you're not storing it in the database? Create out of thin air?!?!?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Concurrency is about multiple users trying to modify the same database row. It's only *via* the database that concurrency conflicts can be detected.

Comment: @marc_s when we said the concurrency check is implemented inside EF, so we excpect to EF create it each time a row fetched to context, i do not want to save it in database. i just need it in runtime not in whole database schema and stored data